# Using Trigger to prevent code inserts in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xss

I have created a trigger to avoid entry of malicious code in my MySQL Table. This table is linked to some Online Form and subsequent report display.

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TRIGGER `tst` BEFORE INSERT ON `test`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
if new.name like '%<%' 
then
signal sqlstate '45000';
end if;
end
```

Will this prevent Code Injection/XSS in the table field "name" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes..though this is not the best way to do this ...you use

```
REPLACE(new.name,"<","&lt;")
```

in trigger. rather you use any sever side script to do this..like php "htmlentities "